# Mobile browsers can not catch closing tab/browser event

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, onbeforeunload, mobile-browser, onunload

I need to catch closing tab/browser on mobile. *onunload* & *onbeforeunload* javascript event can catch refresh page, submit form, redirect page, close tab/browser... It worked perfectly on PC, but when I tried these events on mobile browsers (Chrome on Android, Safari on iOs). It can not catch closing tab/browser event. Please see my code below:

```
 <script>   
    window.onunload = window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        var e = e || window.event;

        // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
        if (e) {        
            //window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
            return "Hello";
        }

        // For Safari   
        //window.open("http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp");
        return "Hello";
    };  
  </script>
  <?php echo "Test onunload and onbeforeunload event"; ?>
```

Could you please advise?

Thanks

Comment: Have you check for onunload? like window.onunload = function(e) {//your code }

Comment: Or try to use JQuery unload function, for more details refer [this](http://api.jquery.com/unload/).

Comment: Yes, I already. But it is the same with window.onbeforeunload.

Comment: This is not possible on mobile phones. You can detect if a tab is closed but not if the browser is closed.